# Is there a way for Conky to display the number of incoming OpenVPN connections without invoking superuser powers?

Tags: networking, openvpn, conky, network-monitoring

Conky is easy to set up to display incoming tcp connections in a useful way:

[image]

I would like to also show incoming OpenVPN connections (udp).

Is there a way to do this in Conky without using `sudo`?  Possibly by using the telnet management interface? Can you script telnet commands and return the output for formatting by `awk`? If so, I could do that.

Comment: Do you have a command that shows this info(even if it is using sudo)? if so you could add it to /etc/crontab and write a text file, and change the owner. and then read the file in conky.

Comment: @Rinzwind yes, there's a status file that exists when a connection is active that can be read using sudo. What you describe is definitely a workable approach. Since I'm not that familiar with Conky I was hoping there was an easier way though.